# How do you completely log out of Azure with Google provider?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-cordova

My scenario is I'm using Visual Studio with Cordova (5.1.1). On a fresh install of the app on my Android device or emulator things work well. I use client.login("google") and I'm given the screen which lets you type in your Google authentication information. Then every time I open the app it just automatically knows which Google account you're using and logs right into Azure with no problems.

My problem is even if I do client.logout() I can't get it to ask for your Google account information again. Does anybody know how to clear that out?

Comment: It's not clear how you are implementing the client.login.  Please add information on: Cordova version, plugins being used, library being used to do the authentication.

Comment: Please share your code sample and the details that Adiran Hall asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The flow for user login should be:

1. `client.login(...`
2. `// User does authenticated actions`
3. `client.logout();`

Logout should clear all session information and invalidate your `zumo_token`.

If this is the behavior you think you've implemented and you believe there is a bug involved, post an issue on the [Azure Mobile Services Codorva GitHub](https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-services-cordova/).